# How to handle multiple exceptions returned by asyncio.gather?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

Java has a concept of suppressed exceptions that can be appended to another exception, ensuring they are not lost.  See: [Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable))

Is there an equivalent in Python 3.x?  I cannot find it.

Why do I need it?  When using `asyncio.gather(..., return_exceptions=True)`, multiple exceptions can be returned.  I would like to merge them into a "super" exception that contains all failures.  In Java, I would pick the first exception, append all other exception, then rethrow the first exception.

If this is not possible in Python, please advise how to handle this scenario.  Please do not recommend to print or log the exceptions.

Finally, I don't know how to better phrase this question.  I am open to edits and suggestions.